# How to execute a shell script in cgi-bin?

Tags: cgi, shellexecute, cgi-bin

OK first of all, I am a PHP programmer but I have never done anything with `CGI` and don't know what it is. I know it stands for Common Gateway Interface, but I do not know what it does or what its for.

I was just told that I can upload a shell script to my cgi-bin folder and execute it.

I made a shell script `myscript.sh` and uploaded it to my cgi-bin folder. The first thing I noticed was my cgi-bin folder is a sibling to my root directory not a child. So I do not know how I would access it?

So I created a directory under my root called `cgi-bin2` and put my script there (and chmod them to 755). Then I accessed it from my browser, and all it did was download the file.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CGI should send a Content-Type header:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"
your_commands_here
```

Save as `anything.sh` (extension does not matter) in your cgi-bin folder and `chmod 755`.
`cgi-bin` does not have to be a child of your public html folder, it can be an [alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Comment: OK so I asked my host to add an alias, they did. I went to `mydomain.com/cgi-bin/myscript.sh` it loads, but just as a blank page. I don't see what I expect. I figured I would at least see the contents of myscript.sh but its blank, even when I view source. A little confused.

Comment: If you get a blank page with an Internal Server Error response, an error occured. Look in your error logs.